# Retrieving form inputs with multiple model classes connected in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a situation where my form looks like this:

```
<form (formGroup)="form" (ngSubmit)="save()" >

<input type="text" (ngModel)="User.name" formControlName="name" />
<input type="text" (ngModel)="User.password" formControlName="password" />
<input type="text" (ngModel)="Register.fullName" formControlName="fullName" />

<input type="submit" />

</form>
```

---

In my component class I have a method save() which look like this:

```
save() {

data = this.form.value;
 console.log("Display User Object :", );

 console.log("Display Register Object :", );
}
```

I want to display the User and Register Object independently when I click the button.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ngModel` you can access the variables like this:

In your component class you need the variables:

```
export class MyComponent {

  public User;
  public Register;

  save() {
    console.log(this.User);
    console.log(this.Register);
  }
}
```

---

In your form:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="User.name">
```

---

The `[()]` is neccessary for Two-Way-Databinding.